# How to deploy cnn file

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have trained a model using this code...

https://github.com/shantanuo/pandas_examples/blob/master/tensorflow/simages_train_waiting.ipynb

My file is ready, but how do I deploy it?

https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/studentimages162a/cnn.h5

I tried to use hosted solution panini.ai but it does not accept h5 files. I tried to convert it to csv but that did not work. I also tried to use flask

https://github.com/mtobeiyf/keras-flask-deploy-webapp

I got this error while trying to run the docker container...

```
# docker run -v /tmp/:/tmp/ -p 5000:5000 keras_flask_app
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 26, in <module>
    model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 221, in _deserialize_model
    model_config = f['model_config']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/io_utils.py", line 302, in __getitem__
    raise ValueError('Cannot create group in read only mode.')
ValueError: Cannot create group in read only mode.
```

In other words how to use cnn.h5 file?

---

I am trying to use this code...

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(output_dim=64, input_dim=100))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=10))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model2 = build_model()
model2.load_weights('cnn.h5')
```

And got the error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 4 layers into a model with 2 layers.
```

Comment: Can you show the code for deployment how you are doing?

Comment: By deployment do you refer to being able to save and reload from disk the H5 model?

Comment: @Siavas Yes! That's correct.

Answer (score 6):

Concerning the first error, I the problem is that the flask app tries to load the complete model (i.e. with configuration):

```
 model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
```

whereas after the training you save only weights:

```
cnn.save_weights('cnn.h5')
```

Try to use `cnn.save('cnn.h5')` instead.

In the second case, your model definition does not match the trained model. Indeed, it is a completely different model with no Convolution layers at all. The corresponding model definition would be:

```
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, 
           kernel_size=(2,2), 
           strides=(1,1),
           padding='same',
           input_shape=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,NB_CHANNELS),
           data_format='channels_last'))


    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),
                           strides=2))

    model.add(Dropout(0.4))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,
                     kernel_size=(2,2),
                     strides=(1,1),
                     padding='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),
                           strides=2))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Comment: I tried to train using your code. Does this look OK? https://github.com/shantanuo/testcnn/blob/master/simages_train_waiting_stack.ipynb

Comment: As Rajneesh Aggarwal suggested, it would be better to call `load_model` to read the configuration from file. If you prefer to define architecture and then load only weights, I can offer you 1) use `build_model` to create `cnn` as well, because currently you have code duplication and 2) give names to the layers and call `model.load_weights(..., by_name=True)`

Answer (score 3):

You can load the model in following way:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('cnn.h5')
```

The training/test data can be loaded with the following code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
hf = h5py.File('cnn.h5', 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trained model and the model you are trying to load differ.
Replace

cnn = Sequential()

with

cnn = build_model()